# how can I do same activity login for these two tables in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

if I have 2 tables in firebase (users and doctors).
when signed in as user, go to userActivity and when signed in as doctor go to another activity.

see my firebase db structure below.

[image]

Comment: How you differentiate a user and a doctor in programming.

Comment: two tables. table users, table doctors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make only one table eq. `tblUser` add extra column say something like `userType`. If user is Doctor then insert 1 else 0 in that column.

While queering back you will get `userType` of that user. Now you can decide which activity should be open. I have added small pseudo code please understand it carefully.

pseudo code

```
//some method like this you need to create.
String userType = getUserType()

if(userType == 0) {
    //Open normal user activity    
} else {
    //open doctor activity
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Marwa Well don't know how is your design for login,but in such case we show the role selection option to the app user so that user will signed in as per there role and then we can use the credentials for login as per user role.